# .htaccess redirect directory to external URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

Using .htaccess how can I redirect "my_directory" to http://www.example.com ?

The catch: the .htaccess file is located in "my_directory", not on the server's "public_html"...

Did not manage to find a definite answer, please help..

Have this so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} **help_with_this_part_please** [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just remove the condition.

Comment: Sumurai8... Which is the condition? :)

Comment: A .htaccess in `my_directory` will be processed _before_ the one at the site root. You only need that `RewriteRule`, not any `RewriteCond`

Comment: Can you plese help with a full script?

Comment: Should I just keep the last line? RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]

Comment: @user3002057 Look at these 3 directives. What one limits when an other directive works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to redirect all from this `.htaccess` in the directory `my_directory`, you can do that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]
```

without `RewriteCond`